# Causality analysis in time series

Tags: time-series, causality, cross-correlation, granger-causality

I'm trying to do a time series analysis, but I'm new to this topic and I need help. I have a multivariable time series and I would like to do an analysis of the relationship between them. I have done a Grange causality test and the results are that there is a lot of grange causality between the time series at different lags.

I'm really doubting these results because the values of the series are from very varied sources. I had previously done a cross-correlation study and only nine of the pairs of series that present grange causality also have a high correlation for the same lag.

I know that a high correlation does not imply causality, but I was looking for some indicator that would allow me to decide when I can be more sure that there really is a causality between two series. I assumed a significance level for the Grange test of 0.01 and correlation values above 0.75 or below -0.75.

One question I have is that several series come from counting some events. These series have many values of 0 because these events have not occurred. Could these values be affecting the result of my analysis?

Another question is whether an analysis of the type can be done in time series: **IF** A occurs **THEN** we must obtain B. This would be something similar to the rules of inference.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is that Granger Causality is not causality. Granger Causality is more like predictability: signal A's earlier values are helpful in predicting signal B.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Adrian Keister. I know that's the case, but I would like to hear criteria on how to determine that the results of the Granger causality test make sense. What other types of tests can be done to look for causality? What other types of relationships can be looked for in multivariate time series?